# Content files do not included

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I am trying to include some files as content in my package. But all samples disregarding of how simple they are for some reason don't work for me.

My nuspec files is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata minClientVersion="3.3.0">
    <id>ContentFilesExample</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>nuget</authors>    <!-- The NuGet team authored this package -->
    <owners>nuget</owners>      <!-- The NuGet team owns this package -->
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>A content v2 example package.</description>
    <tags>contentv2 contentFiles</tags>
    <!-- Build actions for items in the contentFiles folder -->
    <contentFiles>
        <!-- Include Assets as Content -->
        <files include="**/images/*.*" buildAction="EmbeddedResource" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
      <file src="some.dll" target="lib\net45" />
  </files>
</package>
```

My folder structure is:

- ../contentFiles/any/any/images/img.jpg
- ../ContentFilesExample.nuspec
- ../some.dll

I've tried with nuget 3.3.0 and 3.4.4 by running (from PowerShell):
.\nuget.exe pack .\ContentFilesExample.nuspec

The package is created. I can install it and some.dll appears as a reference for my project. But no content files.

Would be thankful for any help